# How to customize navigationbar in GooglePlacePicker on Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I'd have tried to customize NavigationController in GooglePlacePicker on Swift4, but there is not working what I want.

Does anyone know how to change navigation UI in placePicker on Swift4?
Thank you for reading this!

```
@IBAction func pickPlaceBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let config:GMSPlacePickerConfig = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
    print(config.viewport)
    let placePicker:GMSPlacePickerViewController = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)

    placePicker.delegate = self
    present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //Does not work.
    placePicker.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnfP4.png)

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#use_the_uiappearance_protocol

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'd solved this issue!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
placePicker.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
placePicker.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use appearance proxy it will definitely change all of the navigation bars along with GMSPlacePickerViewController navigation bar.For me it worked like this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```